# How to show hide the swipe icons (left and right) based on the width of the container- Javascript /ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a horizontal scroll on a div element using left and right buttons.

```js
document.getElementById('left-button').onclick = function() {
  scrollLeft(document.getElementById('content'), -300, 1000);
}

document.getElementById('right-button').onclick = function() {
  scrollLeft(document.getElementById('content'), 300, 1000);
}

function scrollLeft(element, change, duration) {
  var start = element.scrollLeft,
    currentTime = 0,
    increment = 20;

  console.log(start)

  var animateScroll = function() {
    currentTime += increment;
    var val = Math.easeInOutQuad(currentTime, start, change, duration);
    element.scrollLeft = val;
    if (currentTime < duration) {
      setTimeout(animateScroll, increment);
    }
  };
  animateScroll();
}

Math.easeInOutQuad = function(t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d / 2;
  if (t < 1) return c / 2 * t * t + b;
  t--;
  return -c / 2 * (t * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
};
```

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}

.internal {
  width: 31.75%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <button id="left-button">
        swipe left
      </button>
</div>
<div class="center" id="content">
  <div class=internal>
    div 1
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 8
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <button id="right-button">
        swipe right
      </button>
</div>
```

Taken from [this](https://gist.github.com/andjosh/6764939):

**The divs above are not static, they are dynamically generated div content and is subject to grow**- This is how my page renders,
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kev75n3x/1/)

but based on certain conditions my divs may increase and become like this:
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbfkdz7g/1/)

**Now I want to show these swipe left and swipe right buttons only when the div grow beyond a certain size, I don't want the button to be there even when there is no scrolling required**. (just like scrollbar)
Any idea how to achieve that?

Thanks